# SPFx WebPart started giving TypeError: Cannot read property 'Content' of undefined

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, typescript

This webpart was working on a classic Publishing site. Recently, it started throwing this error message:

**Error details: Error: Error initializing application. Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Content' of undefined**

On an article page the error message is different:

**Error details: Error: Error initializing application. Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'CanvasContent1' of null**

When I place this webpart on a modern page, it works without problems but I do not have the luxury to serve it on a modern page. Another strange thing is that it has to be on the rootweb. It does not work under sub webs anymore.(I am thinking something has changed on microsoft recently...)

I can not even debug it because it works in the local workbench and hosted workbench.

Any ideas on how to solve this? or troubleshooting tips?

Comment: Can you paste the soruce code of the webpart? Especially around the `Content` property?

Comment: I am not sure how to check the Content property. There is no declaration in the SPFx webpart. Also I updated the question with another error message, in case it helps to understand.

Comment: Does htis webpart work fine one a modern page?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: maybe you can create a support ticket with Microsoft